# SOAP webservice endpoint from WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, spring-ws

I am new to the SOAP web service and so referenced one of the tutorial to create a SOAP webservice using Spring.  . I have created the wsdl from the xsd that looks like this.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service"
           targetNamespace="http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="getCountryRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="getCountryResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="country" type="tns:country"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="country">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="population" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="capital" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="currency" type="tns:currency"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="currency">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="GBP"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="EUR"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="PLN"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

I have also created the service endpoint below.

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.PayloadRoot;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.RequestPayload;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.ResponsePayload;

import io.spring.guides.gs_producing_web_service.GetCountryRequest;
import io.spring.guides.gs_producing_web_service.GetCountryResponse;

@Endpoint
public class CountryEndpoint {
    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service";

    private CountryRepository countryRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CountryEndpoint(CountryRepository countryRepository) {
        this.countryRepository = countryRepository;
    }

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getCountryRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public GetCountryResponse getCountry(
            @RequestPayload GetCountryRequest request) {
        GetCountryResponse response = new GetCountryResponse();
        response.setCountry(countryRepository.findCountry(request.getName()));

        return response;
    }
}
```

And configured the bean like this.

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.EnableWs;
import org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.WsConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet;
import org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition;
import org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema;
import org.springframework.xml.xsd.XsdSchema;

@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
    }

    @Bean(name = "countries")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema countriesSchema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("CountriesPort");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("http://localhost:8080/Demo2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ws/");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(countriesSchema);
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

    @Bean
    public XsdSchema countriesSchema() {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("countries.xsd"));
    }
}
```

After deploying the WAR file into tomcat server i am able to see the WSDL at `http://localhost:8080/Demo2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ws/countries.wsdl` which looks like this.

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:sch="http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service" targetNamespace="http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service">
<wsdl:types>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service">
<xs:element name="getCountryRequest">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="getCountryResponse">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="country" type="tns:country"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:complexType name="country">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="population" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element name="capital" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="currency" type="tns:currency"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleType name="currency">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:enumeration value="GBP"/>
<xs:enumeration value="EUR"/>
<xs:enumeration value="PLN"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="getCountryRequest">
<wsdl:part element="tns:getCountryRequest" name="getCountryRequest"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getCountryResponse">
<wsdl:part element="tns:getCountryResponse" name="getCountryResponse"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="CountriesPort">
<wsdl:operation name="getCountry">
<wsdl:input message="tns:getCountryRequest" name="getCountryRequest"></wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:getCountryResponse" name="getCountryResponse"></wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="CountriesPortSoap11" type="tns:CountriesPort">
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="getCountry">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<wsdl:input name="getCountryRequest">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="getCountryResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="CountriesPortService">
<wsdl:port binding="tns:CountriesPortSoap11" name="CountriesPortSoap11">
<soap:address location="`http://localhost:8080/Demo2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ws/`"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

**I am able to see the WSDLon the server but unable to find the service endpoint to send the SOAP request.** I refereed several tutorials but was unable to figure out the endpoint. **Hitting at `http://localhost:8080/Demo2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ws/` returns a 405 error**. Please help me out on this.

Comment: This line at almost the end of your wsdl: `<soap:address location="\`http://localhost:8080/Demo2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ws/\`"/>` Have you tried without the single quotes? like this: `<soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/Demo2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ws/"/>`

Comment: yes, as stack overflow dosen't allow me to mention localhost:8080 I have highlighted the same. My actual wsdl has  <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/Demo2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ws/"/>. Sorry for the inconvinience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Getting a 405 (Method not Allowed) error code when accessing a SOAP service with a browser (i.e. via a GET) is actually correct behavior: all SOAP HTTP access is done via a POST, not a GET.

You can try pointing a SOAP client at the WSDL ( [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org) for example), and see if that works instead.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you would have already solved it but in case not, if you send SOAP request in SOAP UI to http://localhost:8080/Demo2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ws/ it should respond back as this is the location URI that has been set in your Web Service Configuration.

Comment: I don't think you are wrong but remember link only answers, although they may answer the question, can become irrelevant with time; [See this article about how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer):  "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. _Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline_."